# ZSH cloudapp command not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zsh

I've installed cloudapp_api multiple times with:

`sudo gem install cloudapp_api`

I just get this tho when running `cloudapp wat.jpeg`

"You need to install cloudapp_api: gem install cloudapp_api"

I really have no idea what to do.

Not sure if this helps, but i'm running `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]`

Comment: There's no command line executable in the gem from what I can see - https://github.com/aaronrussell/cloudapp_api

Comment: hm? It's not a command line executable its a ZSH command/plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `gem install cloudapp_api`

Comment: Why does that help, when `sudo gem install cloudapp_api` didn't?